# React.js and update JSON Array State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
var DENEMEJSON = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() { return {
    arrayone:[{"id":"1","city":"New York"},{"id":"2","city":"Brooklyn"}],
    arraytwo:[{"id":"101","city":"Hamburg"},{"id":"102","city":"Schalke"}]

}


},
buttonFunc(){
    var str=this.state.arrayone;
    str[0].city="Tokyo";

    this.setState({arrayone:str});
    this.setState({arraytwo:str});
},
buttonFunc2(){
var str=this.state.arrayone;
    str[0].city="Pakistan";
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.arrayone));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.arraytwo));
    this.setState({arrayone:str});
},

 render: function () {
      return (      <div>
        <button onClick={this.buttonFunc}/>
        <button onClick={this.buttonFunc2}/>
        {JSON.stringify(this.state.arrayone)}
        {JSON.stringify(this.state.arraytwo)}</div>
             )
  }//end return

});
```

When I click the first button the code does what I want. It sets the `arrayone[0].city` and `arraytwo[0].city` value to the Tokyo like that.

`arrayone` : `[{"id":"1","city":"Tokyo"},{"id":"2","city":"Brooklyn"}]`

`arraytwo` : `[{"id":"1","city":"Tokyo"},{"id":"2","city":"Brooklyn"}]`

And when I click the second button I only want to set `arrayone[0].city` value to `Pakistan`.(not `arraytwo`).

But the code set both `arrayone[0].city` and `arraytwo[0]` value to `Pakistan`.

Why it sets the `arraytwo[0].value` to `Pakistan`?

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: You shouldn't call `setState` twice in one method. Combine the two `setState` calls in `buttonFunc` like this: `this.setState({arrayone: str, arraytwo: str})`

Comment: I tried that but still the same result.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting it as a fix to your problem - just best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `str` is a reference to `this.state.arrayone`, and you are setting `arraytwo` with `str`.

So when arrayone changes, arraytwo changes too.
It's a bad idea to set your `str` directly with `this.state.arrayone`.
Instead you should clone the state to be able to change what you want to change and update your state ONLY in `setState`.

```
var cloneArrayone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state)).arrayone;
cloneArrayone[0].city = "Tokyo";

this.setState({
  arrayone: cloneArrayone,
  arraytwo: cloneArrayone
});
```

**Here is an example that works**: https://jsfiddle.net/snahedis/69z2wepo/28552/

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is setting arrayone and arraytwo to THE SAME OBJECT REFERENCE when you click the first button.

```
buttonFunc(){
  var str=this.state.arrayone;
  str[0].city="Tokyo";

  this.setState({arrayone:str});
  this.setState({arraytwo:str});
},
```

so when you get arrayone and change the object's value

```
var str=this.state.arrayone;
str[0].city="Pakistan";
```

You changed both arrayone and arraytwo's referenced object

Comment: Thanks, it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when you set both `arrayone` and `arraytwo` to `str`.

```
this.setState({arrayone:str});
this.setState({arraytwo:str});
```

When doing this, both are being assigned a reference to the same object, so any changes made to that object will be made to both of them.

One way around this would be to set both of them separately:

```
var str = this.state.arrayone;
var str2 = this.state.arraytwo;

str[0].city="Tokyo";
str2[0].city="Tokyo";

this.setState({arrayone:str});
this.setState({arraytwo:str2});
```

Or, you could [clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object) the `str` object to make a second, independent copy of it:

```
var str = this.state.arrayone;

str[0].city="Tokyo";

var strCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(str));

this.setState({arrayone:str});
this.setState({arraytwo:strCopy});
```